# Mac, CoreAudio: Crash in AUGraphInitialize()

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio

Our Mac app crashes in AUGraphInitialize() with this backtrace from gdb

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x7004dc2f in PowerMeter::PowerMeter ()
#1  0x70073583 in MatrixMixerCore::MatrixMixerCore ()
#2  0x700461ac in AUMatrixMixer::Initialize ()
#3  0x7000541b in AUBase::DoInitialize ()
#4  0x700a333d in AUMethodInitialize ()
#5  0x91e6056c in _AT_AudioUnitInitialize ()
#6  0x91e75072 in AudioUnitNodeInfo::Initialize ()
#7  0x91e76a62 in AudioUnitGraph::Initialize ()
#8  0x91e77ded in AUGraphInitialize ()
#9  0x008908b6 in CMyCoreAudioWrapper::Init (this=0xc800c80) at MyCoreAudioWrapper:829
...
#18 0x0000c9b7 in main (argc=4, argv=0xbffff8c4) at main.h:7
```

This crash only happens on certain machines, e.g., Mac Pro early 2008, Lion,
and not on others, e.g., Mac Mini late 2012, Mountain Lion. But we don't have 
the resources to test all possible operating environments.

I've narrowed this problem down a little more:

We have only two nodes in the graph, a MatrixMixer node and an Output node.
If I register a callback to the MatrixMixer node, there will be a crash, 
but if the callback is registered to the Output node, no crash.

The callback registration looks like this

```
AURenderCallbackStruct callback = {0};
callback.inputProc          = MixerInputProc;
callback.inputProcRefCon    = this;

result = AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback(m_Graph, m_matrixMixerNode, 0, &callback );
```

I also noticed that even if the callback MixerInputProc() does nothing the crash still happens.

Other things I have tried but didn't work either:

1. Moving around the AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback() to before or after AUGraphOpen(), before or after AUGraphConnectNodeInput(), before or after AUGraphAddNode() calls.
2. Switching the order of calls to AUGraphOpen(), AUGraphAddNode(), AUGraphNodeInfo(), and various SetProperty calls.
3. Use AudioUnitSetProperty() to set input callback for audio unit instead or on top of of node with the category kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback instead of just AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback().
4. Register matrixMixer node to a render callback instead of and input callback. This made no sound at all even though it didn't crash.

Does anyone know quirks about setting callbacks to nodes, such as threading or memory requirements? Things on my mind:

1. **Order sensitivity**: I have seen quite a few code samples in which
   the initialization sequence calls were put in an order that
   roughly looks like this: NewAUGraph() => AUGraphAddNode(),
   AUGraphAddNode(), ..., => GraphConnectNodeInput() => AUGraphOpen()
   => AUGraphNodeInfo(), AUGraphNodeInfo(), ..., various set properties on nodes etc., ...AUGraphInitialize().  Now my question: must this order be absolutely respected??
2. **Callback registration location**:  In the sequence above, when should I insert callback registration code? Before AUGraphOpen or after, for instance.
3. **What's the difference between an "input callback" and a "render callback"?** What is the effect of registering an input callback to a matrix mixer and what about a render callback?
4. **What's the difference between APIs AUGraphAddRenderNotify() and AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback()** other than the fact that they register input/render callbacks, respectively, e.g., thread safety, order in the init sequence, etc.?

CoreAudioAPI mailinglist folks seem to have completely ignored my question so I have to use here as my last straw.

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Pure and simple a bug in Mac OS X mountain lion right? It appears to be affecting people using a variety of apps on OS X Mountain lion.  I have found complaints from various AudioVisual software package users, and I have different Core-Audio related Crashes when I try to plain Steam games on Mac OS X mountain lion.